# Concatenating string names of variables matlabfile in R

Tags: r, csv, while-loop, concatenation, mat

I have matlab files with an integer in each name of my variables inside (except the first one). I want to loop to concatenate the name of the integers.
There is my code:

```
library('R.matlab')
mat <- readMat('SeriesContPJM.mat')
#str(mat)
#typeof(mat)
                                        #mat[[1]]
write.csv(mat$vol.PJM$data[[4]][[1]], "PJM.csv")
i = 2
while (i < 7)
{
    write.csv(get(paste("mat$vol.PJM", as.character(i), "$data[[4]][[1]]", sep = "")), paste(paste("PJM", as.character(i), sep="_"), "csv", sep ="."))
    i = i + 1
}
```

I have `write.csv(mat$vol.PJM$data[[4]][[1]], "PJM.csv")` which gives me the good ouput. I would like the same for the other variable names in the loop but I get the following ouput:

```
+ Error in get(paste("mat$vol.PJM", as.character(i), "$data[[4]][[1]]",  (from importpjm.R#10) : 
  objet 'mat$vol.PJM2$data[[4]][[1]]' introuvable
```

"introuvable" means "not found" in French.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you're mixing where you need to use `get` and where you need to use `eval(parse())`.

You can use `get` with a string variable game, e.g., `get("mtcars")`, but `[` is a function that needs to be evaluated.

- `get("mtcars[2, 2]")` won't work because you don't have a variable named `"mtcars[2, 2]"`, you have a variable named `"mtcars"` and a function named `"["` that can take arguments `2, 2`.
- `eval(parse(text = "mtcars[2, 2]"))` will work because it doesn't just look for a variable, it actually evaluates the text string as if you typed it into the command line.

So, you could rewrite your loop, replacing the `get(...)` with `eval(parse(text = ...))` and it would probably work, assuming the strings you've `paste`d together have the right syntax. But this can be difficult to read and debug. In 6 months, if you look back at this code and need to understand it or modify it, it will be confusing.

Another way to do it would be to use `[[` with strings to extract sublists. Rather than mess with `eval(parse())` I would do this:

```
vols = paste0("vol.PJM", 2:7)
for (vol in vols) {
    write.csv(mat[[vol]][["data"]][[4]][[1]],
              paste0(vol, ".csv"))
}
```

I think it's more readable, and it's easy to debug the `vols` vector beforehand to make sure all your names are correct. Similarly, if you want to loop over all elements, you could initialize the `vols` as something like `names(mat)`, or use some sort of regex criteria to extract the appropriate sublists from `names(mat)`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this very detailed answer. Your final solution is very elegant. Just a question: what the `[[` changes in comparison to the `$`?

Comment: `[[` can be used with strings (and thus with names stored as strings in variables), whereas `$` is a "magical shortcut" that doesn't work with strings. Because `vol` is a string, `mat[[vol]]` works, whereas `mat$vol` won't work. [See this question for more details](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18222286/903061). For the `[["data"]]` bit it doesn't much matter, but since everything else is using `[[` it seemed nice to keep it consistent.