# Varying variables in R in a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

Hi I'm trying to build a code that tries to do the following:

1. lists all the files in a folder
2. extracts the data from each of the excel files (each excel file has multiple sheets and I am using `XLConnect` package to pull the data from different sheets)
3. reshape the data into the format that works best for my data analysis

Here is my code

```
for (i in 1:n) { 
  wb <- loadWorkbook(filelist[i]) 


  assign(paste("field",i,"_reportcontents",sep = ""),
         readWorksheet(wb, sheet="Report Contents"))

  assign(paste("field",i,"_company",sep=""),
         paste("field",i,"_reportcontents[31,3]",sep = ""))
}
```

The way the above code is set up, the second variable, which is field[i]_company is being set as the string "fieldi_reportcontents[31,3]" rather than the value that is in the dataframe field[i]_reportcontents.

How can I fix the code to achieve the values in the data frame rather than allocation of a string?

Comment: @RyanMorton loops don't return things. And OP's `assign` is creating sequentially named objects.

Comment: @mvikred If any of the answers provided solved the problem, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use `assign` and pasting together variable names, I would use lists.

```
wb = lapply(filelist, loadWorkbook)
sheets = lapply(wb, readWorksheet, sheet = "Report Contents")
companies = lapply(sheets, "[", 31, 3)
```

You could easily set the `names` of the lists, e.g.,

```
names(sheets) = sprintf("field_%s_reportcontents", seq_along(sheets))
```

But it isn't clear if this is necessary if you just use good object names with your lists.

See also [How to make a list of data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061) for more soapboxing about the benefits of lists.

Comment: Although not exactly what i was looking for this code is very elegant and I will make use of it in mine. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the sheet being read to a temporary variable. Also, you can replace `paste` with `sep = ""` by `paste0`, it's the same.

```
for (i in 1:n) { 
  wb <- loadWorkbook(filelist[i]) 

  temp <- readWorksheet(wb, sheet="Report Contents")

  assign(paste0("field",i,"_company"),
         temp)
}
```

As for why your last `assign` statement isn't doing what you want, I'll [point you to an answer I wrote yesterday.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41709279/903061) Basically, the value you are trying to assign, `paste("field",i,"_reportcontents[31,3]",sep = "")`, is just a string. You can use `get` with a string to use a variable, but in your case you aren't trying to assign a variable either because you are also using the function `[`, so you would need to parse and evaluate the string you construct. In the end, the `list` approach is a better way to go.

Comment: This works well for me. I've also researched and found mget to be a relevant function here as well. Thanks !